# Nightwatch - unable to locate the element

Tags: xpath, nightwatch

I tried with the following XPath:
`browser.click("//button[normalize-space()='Reserve a room']")`

and receiving the following error message:
 `NoSuchElementError An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`

[image: screenshot]

I tried with the following XPath:
`browser.click("//button[normalize-space()='Reserve a room']")`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just use this css selector:

```
[data-stid="navbar-quick-reserve-button"]
```

Additionally, you can get element selectors easily by right clicking the element in the element console -> hover over Copy -> then select 'Copy Xpath' or 'Copy Selector' for the css selector.

A good way to quickly test if element selectors are valid on the page is doing a Ctrl + F keyboard command from the element tree, then placing it in the element selector you're trying to use. If it's valid, it will be found on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
browser.click('div[data-stid="navbar-quick-reserve-button"] button')
```

This should work also.

```
browser.click('button[data-stid="sticky-button"]')
```